# Where are pointers in C++ stored, on the stack or in the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to understand the difference between the **stack** and **heap** memory, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) on SO as well as [this explanation](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/difference-between-stack-and-heap/) did a pretty good job explaining the basics.

In the second explanation however, I came across an example to which I have a specific question, the example is this:

[image: heap allocation example]

It is explained that the object `m` is allocated on the **heap**, I am just wondering if this is the full story. According to my understanding, the object itself indeed is allocated on the **heap** as the `new` keyword has been used for its instantiation.

However, isn't it that **the pointer to object `m` is on the same time allocated on the stack**? Otherwise, how would the object itself, which of course is sitting in the **heap** be accessed. I feel like for the sake of completeness, this should have been mentioned in this tutorial, leaving it out causes a bit of confusion to me, so I hope someone can clear this up and tell me that I am right with my understanding that this example should have basically two statements that would have to say:

**1. a pointer to object `m` has been allocated on the stack**

**2. the object `m` itself (so the data that it carries, as well as access to its methods) has been allocated on the heap**

Comment: Yes your understanding is right. Pointer is allocated on the stack and the object it is pointing to is allocated on the heap.

Comment: A pointer is an object.  Where an object is located usually depends on its lifetime; objects with static lifetime are located in global memory, objects with dynamic lifetime on the heap, objects with auto lifetime or temporaries on the stack, exceptions in some other special place, etc., etc.  Words like stack or heap are just conventions---simple ways of designating the lifetime, and not some specific location in memory.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your understanding may be correct, but the statements are wrong:

> A pointer to object `m` has been allocated on the stack.

`m` *is the* pointer. It is on the stack. Perhaps you meant *pointer to a `Member` object*.

> The object `m` itself (the data that it carries, as well as access to its methods) has been allocated on the heap.

Correct would be to say *the object pointed by `m` is created on the heap*

In general, any function/method local object and function parameters are created on the stack. Since `m` is a *function local* object, it is on the stack, but the object pointed to by `m` is on the heap.

Answer (score 27):

"stack" and "heap" are general programming jargon. In particular , no storage is required to be managed internally via a stack or a heap data structure.

C++ has the following storage classes

- *static*
- *automatic*
- *dynamic*
- *thread*

Roughly, *dynamic* corresponds to "heap", and *automatic* corresponds to "stack".

Moving onto your question: a pointer can be created in any of these four storage classes; and objects being pointed to can also be in any of these storage classes. Some examples:

```
void func()
{
    int *p = new int;            // automatic pointer to dynamic object
    int q;                       // automatic object
    int *r = &q;                 // automatic pointer to automatic object
    static int *s = p;           // static pointer to dynamic object
    static int *s = r;           // static pointer to automatic object (bad idea)
    thread_local int **t = &s;   // thread pointer to static object 
}
```

Named variables declared with no specifier are *automatic* if within a function, or *static* otherwise.

Comment: +1 mostly for everything before "Moving onto your question" ;) since the question itself is a truism, these added nuances are more important imho.

Comment: Why is a `static pointer to automatic object` bad? Is it because the automatic object will be deallocated when the function ends but the static pointer will live on? Also, if dynamic variables are stored on the heap and automatic variables are stored on the stack, where are static variables stored? This answer really helped me, thank you.

Comment: @JayS. Yes, it's bad because the static pointer will be pointing to an object that no longer exists once the function returns the first time.    "Where things are stored" is a detail of implementations that is beyond the scope of this answer

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a variable in a function, it always goes on the stack.  So your variable `Member* m` is created on the stack.  Note that by itself, `m` is just a pointer; it doesn't point to anything.  You can use it to point to an object on either the stack or heap, or to nothing at all.

Declaring a variable in a class or struct is different -- those go where ever the class or struct is instantiated.

To create something on the heap, you use `new` or `std::malloc` (or their variants).  In your example, you create an object on the heap using `new` and assign its address to `m`.  Objects on the heap need to be released to avoid memory leaks.  If allocated using `new`, you need to use `delete`; if allocated using `std::malloc`, you need to use `std::free`.  The better approach is usually to use a "smart pointer", which is an object that holds a pointer and has a destructor that releases it.

Comment: Does a variable that is declared static in a function end up on the stack? It can't right, considering that is has static allocation ...?

Comment: Correct, typical stack-based C++ implementations do not store statics on the stack.  Statics get stored in a separate area of memory, along-side globals.  So most programs have at least three memory regions for data: the stack, heap, and globals.  In practice, there are often more, but you can ignore those for the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the pointer is allocated on the stack but the object that pointer points to is allocated on the heap. You're correct.

> However, isn't it that the pointer to object m is on the same time
>   allocated on the stack?

I suppose you meant the `Member` object. The pointer is allocated on the stack and will last there for the entire duration of the function (or its scope). After that, the code might still work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Object {
    int somedata;
};

Object** globalPtrToPtr; // This is into another area called 
                         // "data segment", could be heap or stack

void function() {
    Object* pointerOnTheStack = new Object;
    globalPtrToPtr = &pointerOnTheStack;
    cout << "*globalPtrToPtr = " << *globalPtrToPtr << endl;
} // pointerOnTheStack is NO LONGER valid after the function exits

int main() {
     // This can give an access violation,
     // a different value after the pointer destruction
     // or even the same value as before, randomly - Undefined Behavior
    cout << "*globalPtrToPtr = " << *globalPtrToPtr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/BwUVgm

The above code stores the address of a pointer residing on the stack (and leaks memory too because it doesn't free `Object`'s allocated memory with `delete`).

Since after exiting the function the pointer is "destroyed" (i.e. its memory can be used for whatever pleases the program), **you can no longer safely access it**.

The above program can either: run properly, crash or give you a different result. Accessing freed or deallocated memory is called **undefined behavior**.